# Unknown yt page

Tags: reactjs, youtube, react-player

In my project on React i need to play promovideo from YouTube. I use ReactPlayer and i get this error on console:

```
Error: Unknown yt page
    at s.getYtServiceTypeDetails (commons.js:11256:23)
    at s.getServiceType (commons.js:11180:29)
    at s.getPageType (commons.js:11171:29)
    at youtube_com.js:237:25
    at commons.js:9194:9
```

```
<ReactPlayer
    url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some'
    className='react-player'
    height={'100%'}
    width={'100%'}
    playing
    loop
/>
```

Searching did not get any results. Someone knows what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For using embedding youtube videos use the embed link provided by youtube by clicking on share and pressing embed video. For example: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"

Comment: I tried this, same error

Comment: Can you give out more details about the component. Can you create a minimal code production on codesandbox